# Configuraciones para impirmir con react-to-print y react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo ciertas dudas al imprimir usando [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) ya que al momento de querer imprimir cualquier objeto me queda de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo no quiero que se imprima de la siguiente forma yo quiero que se imprima asi (sin los botones)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero esta impresion, solo de logra cuando preciono click derecho y selecciono la opcion de imprimir, no con el boton que tengo designado, y queria saber si se tiene que hacer alguna configuracion antes de mandarlo a imprimir o si se tiene que settear algun atributo de react-to-print?

mi codigo que crear el handler para impirmir:

```
const handlerPrint = useReactToPrint({
    documentTitle: `Reporte de Textiles- ${reporte}`,
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    bodyClass:'container',
    trigger: async (event) => { console.log(event) },
    suppressErrors: true,
    pageStyle:'width: 100vw',
    removeAfterPrint: true,
    copyStyles: true,
    onAfterPrint: (event) => {
        setReporte("")
        swal("Reporte creado", "El reporte fue creado satisfactoriamente!", "success")
        axios.post('/securityLog', {
            action: `Usuario exporto un reporte de textiles con codigo: "${fields.codigo}" .`,
            author: authorMail
        })
    }
})
```

quiero aclarar que estoy usando bootstrap, tenen algo que ver el hecho de que lo este usando? y de ser asi como que puedo hacer para modificar y que aparesca como yo quiero